# Executable jar file window size is bigger and not as sharp as when opened via netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, jframe, executable-jar

When I clean and build my java application and run the .jar file, it is bigger and not as sharp as when I run it via netbeans. I couldn't figure out the reason for it, I tried to fix the frame sizes, but nothing has changed. enter image description here
Here's a picture of it:
[image]